# How can I run a python script without python.exe

Tags: python, windows, scripting

My goal is to have a python script that I can giving to someone to run on their windows machine that does not have python installed. I do want to package it up in an exe because I want the underlying code to be easily read.

I am updating an old VBscript and I want to mirror it. I am also using a few libraries.

Comment: huh? whats your question? you do want to make an EXE? or you want to distribute source code?

Comment: I want to right a script similar to a .vbs or a .bat but in python.

Comment: You can include a portable Python interpreter that doesn't need to be installed. But if that's too much, then Python is not the answer for you. Unlike Linux and MacOS, Windows is not distributed with support for Python. The Windows Scripting Host (cscript.exe / wscript.exe) also supports Javascript if you prefer that over VBScript.

Comment: go to http://repl.it/languages/python ... create your program ... share your link

Comment: @JoranBeasley does that work if I am using a library like wmi?

Answer (score 0):

use pyinstaller to package it up to an exe. You can still maintain your source code. Packaging it up wont remove your source code.

Comment: if hes asking about this then sure this answer is ok ... its still pretty weak... but im not sure how you were able to parse this out of the question, as it is...

Comment: I understand that I would still have the source code if I packaged it into an exe. I would want my python code to run like a VBscript, like being able to run the .vbs script but also able to edit that same file.

Comment: In which case I dont think python is the right choice for you, as from what I am aware, you will need python installed. Maybe some one can chip in with some thing that will be new to us both.

Comment: @Adam That would be nice